# Filter Pages in laravel

Tags: filter, laravel-4

i'm a rookie in laravel.

I have a page in admin profile (/Profile /admin). But if someone put

> http:// ... / Profile/admin

. Happen a jump directly to the admin page without login.

I tried putting:

```
Route::filter ('/Profile/admin',function ()
{
      if (Auth::guest ()) return Redirect::guest ('login');
});
```

but i dosen't work.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can run filters on your routes to basically check to see if someone is logged in or not. There is probably a bit you need to do to make sure all is secure.

However, suggested reading:

http://laravel.com/docs/routing#route-filters

http://laravel.com/docs/security

Hope it helps.